# How to copy over a 2D array of string to a new 2D array of string, but I don't want to include the right two columns of the original array

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array, 2d

```
int[][] imageData={{100,90,255,80,70,255,60,50},
                                 {255,10,5,255,10,5,255,255},
                                 {255,255,255,0,255,255,255,75},
                                 {255,60,30,0,30,60,255,255}};
    
    //First, we want to crop the image down to a 4x6 image, removing the right 2 columns. Declare and initialize a new 2D array of integers with 4 rows and 6 columns called `newImage`.
    int[][] newImage = new int[4][6];
```

Below is the question I'm trying to solve and below is the code of what I have tried to solve the question.

```
//Now that you have your empty image, use nested **for** loops to copy over the data from the original image to the new image, make sure not to include the cropped out columns. (right 2 columns).
for(int i = 0; i < newImage.length; i++) {
  for(int j = 0; j < imageData.length; j++) {
    newImage[i + 0][j + 2] = imageData[i][j + 3];
  }
}


    System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(newImage));
```

Below is the output am getting from the console.

```
[[0, 0, 80, 70, 255, 60], [0, 0, 255, 10, 5, 255], [0, 0, 0, 255, 255, 255], [0, 0, 0, 30, 60, 255]]
[[0, 0, 80, 70, 255, 60], [0, 0, 255, 10, 5, 255], [0, 0, 0, 255, 255, 255], [0, 0, 0, 30, 60, 255]]

    //You want to decrease the brightness of the new image by 50 units. The way this works is that for every integer in the new 2D array, we will subtract the value by 50. Remember that the value range for the pixel is 0-255, so if the result tries to go below 0, just set it equal to 0.
        
        
        System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(newImage));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
int[][] imageData={{100,90,255,80,70,255,60,50},
            {255,10,5,255,10,5,255,255},
            {255,255,255,0,255,255,255,75},
            {255,60,30,0,30,60,255,255}};

int[][] newImage = new int[4][6];
    
for (int i=0; i<imageData.length; i++) {
   newImage[i] = Arrays.copyOfRange(imageData[i], 0, imageData[i].length-2);
}
```

`newImage` will contain the desired data.

Arrays.copyOfRange() is a function which will take `array`, `fromIndex` and  `toIndex`as arguments and will give the corresponding `subArray`
You can read more [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/java-util-arrays-copyofrange-java/)

Comment: Thanks this way to solve the question help even duo the question was about using nested for loop. You use regular for loop to solve it which help to show difference ways to solve the same question.

Answer (score 1):

```
for(int i = 0; i < imageData.length; i++) {
  for(int j = 0; j < imageData[i].length - 2; j++) {
    newImage[i][j] = imageData[i][j];
  }
}
```

Here the values should remain in the same positions. Change them if you need them in different locations.

If all inner arrays have the same length, then you can define a constant for that length so it improves the program efficiency (marginally).

Side note: The zeros in your int[][] are the default values when you define an int, or int arrays.

Comment: Thanks for taking your time to help me and you did help solve the solution to the question.